# Cannot get url.rewrite and alias.url to play nice together

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

Current relavent config from lighttpd.conf:

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/(.*)\.(.+)$" => "$0",
    "^/(.+)/?$" => "/index.php/$1",
)
```

and

```
alias.url += (
  "/xcache/" => "/usr/share/xcache/"
)
```

I cant get them to work together. From what I understand, the rewrite hijacks the "/xcache/" url thus not triggering the alias.url.

They both work perfectly fine on their own, but cannot get them to work together. Is there a way to exclude certain strings from the url.rewrite expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/(xcache)/(.*)" => "$0",
    "^/(.*)\.(.+)$" => "$0",
    "^/(.+)/?$" => "/index.php/$1",
)
alias.url += (
  "/xcache/" => "/usr/share/xcache/"
)
```